# How do I call a Laravel commands handle from the command itself?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a command like this

```
class TestCommand extends Command {
 .....
 constructor
 .....

 public function handle()
 {
    ....
    command logic
    ....
 }
}
```

the `TestCommand`is registered in the `Kernel.php` also.

now I need to extend `TestCommand`,

```
class ExtendedCommand extends TestCommand {

  public function __construct ()
  {
    parent::__constrct();
    .....
    modify some variables
    .....
  }

  public function sync()
  {
     //trying to call the parent class handle method.

     $this->handle(); // not working & getting PHP Error:  Call to a member function getOption() on null in /home/vagrant/sinbad/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php on line 292
     $this->execute(); // obviously not working & getting TypeError: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(),
  }
}

//instantiating the new command
   new(ExtendedCommand)->sync();
```

Now I need to call the `ExtendedCommand` what are the possible ways I can do it? a solution without registering this command in the `kernel.php` would be better, cause I am not looking for an `Artisan::call` way.

Comment: You need to separate the logic to another class.

Comment: how can I do it @Alfa ?

Comment: wouldn't `(new ExtendedCommand())->sync()` work? However consider this. You're writing a command which you want to use as though it where just a regular class. Does it have to be a command?

Comment: Its not working, @apokryfos, Thats why i asked the question :)

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem @ShobiPP?

Comment: I think my point still remains. If you don't need a command don't create a command. Extending an existing command because you need part of its functionality makes me think that functionality can be put elsewhere.

Comment: @apokryfos, yes you are right, I ended up not writing a command.

Answer (score 1):

More like this

```
<?php

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(Handler $handler)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->handler = $handler;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->handler->handle();
    }
}

// No need to extends from TestCommand
class ExtendedCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(Handler $handler)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->handler = $handler;

        // do the rest
    }

    public function sync()
    {
        $this->handler->handle();
        $this->execute();
    }
}

class Handler
{
    public function handle()
    {
        // Put your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: In your solution , the `$this->execute();` part is failing. since it requires the Input and Output parameters. I was not able to figure it out myself. but the separation of logic in some way helped me. thanks. +10

Comment: That's just a pseudo code. You may pass another argument to that method.